# Как смапить сложный Json объект?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Вот пример строки:

```
{
  "code":200,
  "err":"",
  "timestamp":1459855918,
  "data":{
    "city":[
      {
        "cityid":3877,
        "cityname":"",
        "districts":[
          {"id":1245, "name":"", "sort":0},
          {"id":1257,"name":"","sort":0},
          {"id":1461,"name":"","sort":0},
          {"id":1338,"name":"","sort":0}
        ]
      },
      {
        "cityid":2263,
        "cityname":"",
        "districts":[
          {"id":1223,"name":"","sort":0},
          {"id":1203,"name":"","sort":8},
          {"id":1048,"name":"","sort":8},
          {"id":1205,"name":"","sort":999}
        ]
      }
    ]  
  }
}
```

POJO class:

```
public class ObjectGetDictionary {

private int code;

private String err;

private long timestamp;

private List<city> data;

//геттеры + сеттеры


class city {

    private int cityid; 

    private String cityname;

    private List<district> districts;

    //геттеры + сеттеры

    class district {

        private int id;

        private String name;

        private int sort;

        //геттеры + сеттеры

        district(){};
    }
    city(){};
}
ObjectGetDictionary(){};
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
ObjectGetDictionary res = mapper.readValue(content, ObjectGetDictionary.class);
```

Как обычно конвертируются такие сложные объекты?

Comment: Как бы классы всегда называют с большой буквы.

Comment: В общем-то примерно как у вас: делается модель для всех уровней вложенности.

Comment: Можно воспользоваться генератором - http://jsonschema2pojo.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вариант (в общих чертах):

**1. Создаем класс `Response`**

например так:

```
class Response {
    private int code;
    private String errorMessage;
    private Timestamp timestamp;
    private String data;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**2. Создаем класс `City`**

```
class City {
    @SerializedName("cityId");
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("cityname");
    private int name;
    private List<District> districtList;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**3. Создаем класс `District`**

```
class District {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int sort;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**4. Десериализуем:**

Нам понадобится [JSONObject](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) и [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) либа от Google

Через `JSONObject` получаем из Response строки JSON-объект
у которого дергаем поле `data`. Проверяем наличие поля `city`, выдергиваем из него список городов. Крутим список городов в цикле и попутно десериализуем в POJO:

```
JSONObject data = response.get("data");

if (data.has("city")) {
    JSONArray city = data.get("city");

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    // цикл по city
    // десериализуем
    City city = gson.fromJson(object, City.class);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Вопрос: почему в классе city мы указали соответствующие в Json @SerializedName("") поля, а в District - нет?

Comment: затем чтобы сделать соответствие полей чьи имена различаются (JSON <-> POJO), в District все окей с именами и полями